# PRODUCT_ID as primary key rather then the UPC(UNIVERSAL PRODUCT CODE)

Tags: mysql, eav

I have a very strange kind of question in my mind, I'm using the `EAV` model in my E-COMMERCE DB. I have a `product` table with primary key `p_id` which is auto_increment, and to save its attributes I have a different table `product_attribute`, that also stores SKU of every product and have `p_id` as FOREIGN KEY, which there I am using `attribute-value` pair. So, my question is, if I missed storing a product of `size` `7` of any product of a company `A` in `product_attribute` table and stored all the other sizes. How, will I know that what was my `p_id` for the product I missed at a later time when I want to store it? SHOULD I use UPC instead of `p_id`?

Comment: SKU vs UPC -- debate the advantages/disadvantages of using each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-increment IDs are what's called *surrogate keys*. In most cases, data has some sort of a natural key as well. In your case, it sounds like the natural key is the UPC.

So, if there's a natural key, why create a surrogate key? There are several reasons. Two of the most important to me are size and changeability.

When a natural key is a `varchar` or `nvarchar` value, that key is frequently much larger than 4 bytes (the size of an `int`). For frequently used keys, the space difference involved can be noticeable.

Also, natural keys are most often values that have a meaning outside of the database. It may happen rarely, but occasionally something like a UPC code may change. If it's used as the key to your product table, updating all references to it can take a long time, and require a large number of locks.

In your example, I assume that the product of size 7 that didn't get entered would still have its UPC available. If so, you'd look up the UPC code's `product_id`, and use that value in your EAV table.

If the UPC is not stored in the database, some sort of identifying information still must be. Use the SKU of one of the related products (for example), or (better yet) add an appropriate overall description to the `product` record so you can locate it. If there's nothing related in the database, then logically the product ID could be anything, and wouldn't have to be connected to any existing data.

Comment: BUT in case we dont have any natural keys like the UPC,then how we can get which `product_id` the product is related to??there are going to be a lot of other `product_id`'s, and we need to get the right `product_id` otherwise it will be added to some other product

Comment: I have seen at some databases, they don't usually store the UPC, but have SKU(and they all are different for a single product of different attribute),AND we can't tell by looking at the actual product thaT, what can be it's `product_id` in our DB

Comment: If your product is already in your database, then you presumably have *some* way to locate it. Use the SKU of one of the related products, or add an appropriate overall description to the `product` record so you can locate it. If there's nothing related in the database, then logically the product ID could be anything, and wouldn't have to be connected to any existing data.

Comment: Is the UPC in the main table?  In the attribute table?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and tell us whether UPC is in either table.  How would you look for something of size 7, anyway?

Comment: @RickJames,I am not using UPC,that is why I want to use the auto_increment `prod_id`,neither of my tables have UPC,that is what my next question in mind is(how to look for something size 7),I have told it in my question above too

Comment: @RDFozz using the SKU of a related product is a nice idea,it can solve my problem, I had this in  my mind earlier,but I think there can be a better way....